# Weird behavior in Rust with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, rust, rust-cargo

I am trying Rust (ver 1.4.0) these days, and coding with [opencv-rust](https://github.com/kali/opencv-rust) library.

I wrote some code like this.

```
extern crate opencv;

use self::opencv::highgui;
use self::opencv::core::Mat;

fn main() {
    load("image/test4.jpg");
}

fn load(path: &str) {
    let src: Mat = highgui::imread(path, 1).unwrap();

    if src.empty().unwrap() {
        println!("Img load error");
    }
    else {
        println!("Img load success");
    }
}
```

When I run `cargo run` it shows `Img load error`.

However, when I added a `println!` at first line in `load` function like

```
fn load(path: &str) {
    println!("whatever");
    let src: Mat = highgui::imread(path, 1).unwrap();

    if src.empty().unwrap() {
        println!("Img load error");
    }
    else {
        println!("Img load success");
    }
}
```

It shows `Img load success`.

But when I change it to other code like `let a: i32 = 1;`, it shows `Img load error` again.

I have no idea what's going on.

System info:

- OS: Manjaro Linux
- Kernel: 4.3.0

Comment: sounds like undefined behavior, you should report a bug in the `opencv` crate.

Comment: @ker So it's not rust problem about passing str or what?

Comment: Knovour: no, it's definitely a library issue. If you get odd behavior in safe code, the issue is in the unsafe code. since your only unsafe code is the one in the opencv crate, it must be there.

Comment: It's fixed, we should close the question as "the problem can no longer be reproduced".

Answer (score 1):

This bug was [reported](https://github.com/kali/opencv-rust/issues/12) and [fixed](https://github.com/kali/opencv-rust/commit/a3309d45917ae0081a93dd920611d629deae2930). Version 0.2.2 should now work.